# Storing large amounts of data in state?

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I'm building a simple forum trying to take it one step at a time. The first step is just trying to get the data that I fetched from my database onto my page. However, I'm asking myself in the long run when this goes to production, is this the right approach to take when I'm fetching all records from my database and setting it to state and then displaying it in the view of my page?

Reason I'm concerned about this is because down the long run, if I have let's have 20,000 forum posts all 20k of those records would be stored inside of my state in arrays that I have fetched from my database?

I have read articles about using redux but I prefer not to use that approach because I'm still in the process of learning react and am just wondering if their was a better approach to doing this?

Also, my assumption is I am taking the right approach but I would have only  let's say 10-20 load at a time until the user requests to see more?

Here is my code:

**Model:** (this query will obviously be changed I'm just trying to putt data onto my page to make sure it works.)

I guess this is also more of seeking advise question rather than getting help with my code I wasn't sure where else to ask.

```js
var db = require('../dbconnection');

var forumPage = {
    postTopic: function (data, callback) {
        var datetime = new Date();
        var createdDate = datetime.getFullYear()+ '-' + (datetime.getMonth()+1) + '-' + datetime.getDate()

        db.query("insert into forum_topics set topic_name=?, topic_message=?, created_date=?", [data.questionTitle, data.questionBody, createdDate], callback);
    },
    selectTopics: function(data, callback) {
        db.query("SELECT * from forum_topics order by created_date desc", callback);
    }
}

module.exports = forumPage;
```

**View:**

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

import Header from '../common/Header';
import ForumpageService from '../../services/forumService';
import Forumposttopic from './ForumpostTopic';

class Forumpage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            searchQuery: '',
            questionHead: [],
            questionBody: [],
            questioncreatedDate: [],
            questionmodifiedDate: [],
        }
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleClose(){
        this.setState({
            show:false,
        });
    }

    handleShow(){
        this.setState({
            show:true
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const selecttopicsData = await ForumpageService.selectTopics();
        for(let i = 0; i < selecttopicsData.length; i++) {
            this.setState({
                questionHead: [...this.state.questionHead, selecttopicsData[i].topic_name],
                questionBody: [...this.state.questionBody, selecttopicsData[i].topic_message],
                questioncreatedDate: [...this.state.questioncreatedDate, selecttopicsData[i].created_date],
                questionmodifiedDate: [...this.state.questionmodifiedDate, selecttopicsData[i].modified_date],
            })

        }
        //console.log(selecttopicsData);
        console.log(this.state);

    }




    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container" id="forum-container">
                <Header />
                <form
                    method="POST"
                    onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}
                    autoComplete="off"
                >
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4" id="questionBox">
                            <button className="btn btn-default" id="searchButton">
                                <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="searchQuery"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="searchBox"
                                placeholder="Search..."
                                onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
                                value={this.state.searchQuery}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-8" id="askquestion">
                            <Button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleShow}>Ask a Question</Button>
                        </div>
                        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                <Modal.Title>Question?</Modal.Title>
                            </Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body>
                                <Forumposttopic />
                            </Modal.Body>
                        </Modal>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <table className="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th id="topic">Topic</th>
                                    <th id="replies">Replies</th>
                                    <th id="latest">Latest Post</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            //// This is where I would map over fetched data. But I'm concerned in the future that this will cause a problem if I set all data that I fetched from my db into state all at once.
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="topic-message">
                                        <h2>Dummy Data first post</h2>
                                        <p id="responsetext">Proin vitae ornare tortor. In suscipit diam tortor, et pellentesque lectus tincidunt eget. Integer nisi leo, vestibulum vitae tincidunt a, suscipit eu massa. Cras ut enim tortor.</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="replies-message">
                                        <p>4</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="latest-message">
                                        <p>Random User</p>
                                        <p>Created Date: 05/03/18</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Forumpage;
```

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. You're starting, don't worry about that kind of large scenarios. In the event that you get to 20k posts you likely won't fetch all of them at once, and for large amounts of in-memory data there are alternatives to plain arrays that perform better. But take your own advice about redux and apply it to this. When you get around to the 19997th post you probably will have a better idea of what to do :)

Comment: I didn't know about that. Okay thank you for the advise I'll take that into consideration when I'm building out the application and worry about any inefficiencies for later. Thank you!

Comment: This is a technical challenge the back end should be facing. Not the front end. It seems a little silly to try and front load that much data. You can't even meaningfully render that much data on one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux isn't going to help you store less in your state. If you have a forum normally you would have different sub forums and threads below that. Each thread then has a multiple pages if necessary so you should never need to display more than say 50 posts at a time. And you can just query and split stuff up in your database and then just store the part the user sees in state. There is no point in a database if you are just going to select everything and then put it in state.

I'm not sure what version of sql you are using so the syntax might be different but I did something similar with a table that had sometimes hundreds of thousands of pages. I would just store the page number in state then use that in my limit statement in my sql.

For example if you change your select statement and order it by for example date posted then do limit 0, 10 then 10, 10 then 20, 10 etc then you will never need to store more than 10 posts in your state and they will always come back in the same order on each page of your forum thread.

```
this.state = {
  thread: 'my cool topic',
  limit: 20,
  index: 0,
  pages: 0
}
```

When you do your first query you can do a count to know how many pages you should render in your list. Then you just query by your limit and index and increment it in your state depending on user actions.

**The key is to build your query from your state. The current method you have builds your state from your query.**

Comment: I see okay so it's more of modifying my query and getting it right and then building my state off of that. I will take this into consideration. Thank you for advice.

Comment: Exactly! Good luck